# How to using pycurl resolve this curl call?

Tags: python, pycurl

```
curl -v -S -k -u 'user:pwd' -X POST -H 'X-USER-SERVICE-NAME:usertenacy' --form 'data=@manager_logs.zip' "https://testservice/serviceapi/logan.uploads?uploadName=param1&appendUpload=param2&logSourceName=param3"
```

How to use pycurl to resolve this curl call above?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: curl_instance = pycurl.Curl()
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.URL, service_url)
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, user_pwd)
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.UPLOAD, 1)

        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, [("data", (pycurl.FORM_FILE, "messages.txt"))])
        curl_instance.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, [("parameters", data)])
        curl_instance.perform()

Comment: Please use the `edit` button to add this code in your question, and explain how it doesn’t work and what you have tried to fix it.